# 'Pretty' visualization not applied in Combo Chart

Tags: google-visualization

I'm trying to format nicely [this Combo Chart](http://jsfiddle.net/9hsp9107/5/), so that the vertical axes on both sides share the same gridlines. However, the second Y-axis (right side) isn't formatted as `viewWindowMode: 'pretty'` automatically. The result is that the values start from 0 instead of 10,000.

By setting the min and max values:

```
viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
    viewWindow: {
        max: 14000,
        min: 10000}
```

the outcome is nice, but the line touches top and bottom of the chart. So I tried giving it some padding by setting `max: 15000`and `min: 9000`, but then the number of gridlines increases and `gridlines: {count: 6}`doesn't seem to have an effect.

Is there a way to force `viewWindowMode: 'pretty'` on the second vertical axis?

Answer (score 0):

The 'pretty' mode for an axis is going to result in unpredictable values, depending on where your data falls within the gridlines.  So if you wish to coordinate the gridlines for both the left and right axes, you need to be more explicit about the viewWindow min and max for both, and the number of gridlines, or explicit ticks.  You could do it like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/dlaliberte/pyAz5/316/  Which uses these options:

```
var options = {
  series: { 
    1: { targetAxisIndex: 1 }
  },
  vAxes: {
    0: {
      viewWindow: { min: 0, max: 1500 }
    },
    1: {
       viewWindow: { min: 0, max: 1500 }
    }
  }
};
```

The gridlines.count option is not a guarantee in all cases because it could conflict with the heuristics for nice tick values.

Comment: The problem is that my scales have different orders of magnitude, so setting them same doesn't work.

Comment: You can account for the different scale for each. Set the viewWindow accordingly, and then maybe use the explicit ticks option to specify exactly the ticks you want for each axis.